# typescript trying to use dynamic require but isn't working

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6, commonjs

well I'm trying to `require` a `module` from `node_modules` dynamically like:

```
export function tryRequire(path: string): any {
  try {
    //TODO :: find a better way

    //for testing bypass it
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") return {};

    return require(`${path}`).default;
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

which gets compiled from `TypeScript` to `JavaScript` as:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.tryRequire = tryRequire;

function tryRequire(path) {
  try {
    //TODO :: find a better way
    //for testing bypass it
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") return {};

    return require("".concat(path));
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

now when I try to use it in `Javascript` say like :

```
tryRequire("react-native")
```

it doesn't work , is there something missing here?

EDITED: what interesting is , if I edited the compiled code , and I replaced : `return require("".concat(path));` with `return require("react-native"); , it works just fine!

Comment: Are you sure `process.env.NODE_ENV` is correctly set when you are running your script? Maybe the `require` is skip because the function ends before.

Comment: @KevinPastor yes the `NODE_ENV` is `development`

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391